# php with bootstrap carousel single <li> slide

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently added bootstrap carousel in my project and it works fine but here I have selected noOfProductPage=4 which I want by default and then instead of sliding all 4 products I want individual product to slide in when user clicks next

PHP:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
</a>
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < $noOfProductPage; $i++) {  
        $targetActiveClass = "";
        if ($i == 0) {
            $targetActiveClass == "active";
        } 
    ?>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php echo $targetActiveClass; ?>"></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

In short data-slide-to should be just one product not 4..

Answer (score 0):

Use `interval`, like:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: flase
});
```

Hope this helps!

More about **[Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)**

Comment: I am doing this and instead of one image I am using col-md-3 and using 4 small images but when I slide I want only one image of my slide to slide on clicking next arrow

Comment: @Ron Do no use `col-md-3` or these classes, use the `item` class. Read the doc properly (link in my answer)

Comment: I have to use col-md-3 to display 4 images properly and then I want to change them one image at a time
For example I have 11 images total by default I display 4 in first slide then for every next or prev just one image should change

Comment: @Ron Just put them inside `item` not `col-md-3`, carousel itself will make it full width.

Comment: I tried that carousel makes one image full width and remaining 3 beneath it

Comment: @Ron If possible, please show me the code snippet on codepen or jsfiddle.